# Understand how to address "td" elements

Tags: html, excel, vba

I would like to understand the concept on how to address in VBA a single td element in HTML with getelements, for example if I want to address the last td element below that has inside 103,48 and just after "Prezzo di chiusura?

```
<div class="instruments_company_summary">
      <table class="table-noborders">
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label"> </td>
          <td>
            <div class="floatdx" style="padding-bottom:10px">
              <div class="floatsx">
                <div class="standard-button">
                  <a href="/it/strumenti/grafico/IT0004781073">Grafico</a>            </div>
              </div>
                          <div class="floatsx">
                  <div class="standard-button">
                    <a href="http://www.eurotlx.com/product-details/IT0004781073.pdf" target="_blank">Scheda</a>              </div>
                </div>
                                  <div class="floatsx">
                <div class="standard-button">
                  <a href="/it/strumenti/dettaglio/csv/IT0004781073">Scarica book</a>            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Isin</td>
          <td>
            <div class="floatsx" style="padding-top:4px;">IT0004781073</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Descrizione</td>
          <td>Bpvi 8.5% Sink Sub 28dc18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Prezzi aggiornati al</td>
          <td>08-11-2015 13:51:45</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Book di negoziazione</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Var</td>
          <td>0,10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label" style="border:0">Book a 5 livelli</td>
          <td style="border:0; padding: 10px 0 5px">
            <table>
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Q.tà Acquisto</th>
                <th>Prezzo Acquisto</th>
                <th>Prezzo Vendita</th>
                <th>Q.tà Vendita</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                            <tr>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                          </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Dati ultimo contratto</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Prezzo</td>
          <td>103,6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Quantità</td>
          <td>24.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Data e ora</td>
          <td>06-11-2015 17:29:41</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Dati giornalieri</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="table_label">Prezzo di chiusura</td>
          <td>103,48</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: How is this different from [I want to get a specific HTML td tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586677/i-want-to-get-a-specific-html-td-tag)?

Comment: Rocco, we need to know how you are accessing that html code, do you have any VBA code yet? What library/objects are you using? (probably you would use the InternetExplorer object or MSXML2 library...)

Comment: Take another look @JasonK.

Comment: I will answer with the code I am using now it works but probably there is a better way to access td elements, please take a look I would like to understand better how to access the HTML

Comment: I posted the code I am using below, the URL I am using is http://www.eurotlx.com/it/strumenti/dettaglio/IT0004785355, now I just counted the td numer in the web page but I think there is a better way to access it. Let me know what would be the better way to access it in your opinion

Comment: the index in the code is a number and it will point to the cell where i want to save the data inside the td tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try to get some data from a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618537/try-to-get-some-data-from-a-web-site)

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using this code and it works, I get the td element I want as td number in the web page, but I thought there could be a better way to identify the td cell.

```
Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
    Dim Objie As Object
    Dim xObj
    Debug.Print URL

    Set Objie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Objie.Visible = False

    Objie.Navigate URL

    While (Objie.Busy Or Objie.ReadyState <> 4)
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set xObj = Objie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(39)

    W.Range("E" & Index + 1) = xObj.innerText

    Set xObj = Nothing
    Objie.Quit
    Set Objie = Nothing
```