# Try to get some data from a web site

Tags: html, excel, vba

I would like to get a different prices from financial site and store them in an Excel file.
I don't have good knowledge and I would like to know if the code I did to get data from a web site is the best or it could be done better.
The web site HTML code is this one. I would like to get the last td at the end just after 'Prezzo di chiusura' that has inside 103,74.

I have these questions:

- I used the get elementsbytagname("td")(39) , I have just counted the the td number in the page, is there a better way to address that td ?
- I noticed that sometime I have previous price and not the one I see in the web page, with my code do I access a different area data that the one I see in the web page and until it is not updated I will see only the previous data?

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="instruments_company_summary">
  <table class="table-noborders">
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label"> </td>
      <td>
        <div class="floatdx" style="padding-bottom:10px">
          <div class="floatsx">
            <div class="standard-button">
              <a href="/it/strumenti/grafico/IT0004785355">Grafico</a>            </div>
          </div>
                      <div class="floatsx">
              <div class="standard-button">
                <a href="http://www.eurotlx.com/product-details/IT0004785355.pdf" target="_blank">Scheda</a>              </div>
            </div>
                              <div class="floatsx">
            <div class="standard-button">
              <a href="/it/strumenti/dettaglio/csv/IT0004785355">Scarica book</a>            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Isin</td>
      <td>
        <div class="floatsx" style="padding-top:4px;">IT0004785355</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Descrizione</td>
      <td>Bpvi 7% 29dc16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Prezzi aggiornati al</td>
      <td>09-11-2015 21:28:48</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Book di negoziazione</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Var</td>
      <td>0,05%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label" style="border:0">Book a 5 livelli</td>
      <td style="border:0; padding: 10px 0 5px">
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Q.tà Acquisto</th>
            <th>Prezzo Acquisto</th>
            <th>Prezzo Vendita</th>
            <th>Q.tà Vendita</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                        <tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>-</td>
            </tr>
                      </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Dati ultimo contratto</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Prezzo</td>
      <td>103,93</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Quantità</td>
      <td>5.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Data e ora</td>
      <td>09-11-2015 16:59:33</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Dati giornalieri</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table_label">Prezzo di chiusura</td>
      <td>103,74</td>
    </tr>
```

The Excel VBA code is this one:

```
Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
Dim Objie As Object
Dim xObj

Set Objie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Objie.Visible = False

Objie.Navigate "http://www.eurotlx.com/it/strumenti/dettaglio/IT0004785355"

While (Objie.Busy Or Objie.ReadyState <> 4)
    DoEvents
Wend

Set xObj = Objie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(39)

W.Range("I3" ) = xObj.innerText

Set xObj = Nothing
Objie.Quit
Set Objie = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be better (insulates you from changing numbers of rows in previous tables)

```
Dim tbl, xObj

Set tbl = Objie.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3) '4th table on page
Set xObj = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td")(2)              'second td in that table
```

Comment: Tx the last one is getelements("td")(1) instead of (2)

Comment: May ask you the other question, do you have an idea why for example now I have not the data I see in the site but the data of the previous day? Maybe because I access another memory area that the one it uses for the webpage, now I have 103,88 while in the site is 103,74 the today price

Answer (score 0):

You can also search for your desired data ("PREZZO DI CHIUSURA") and get the value given to it using the `nextElementSibling` Property. This way, you can be always be sure that the value obtained is independent of the table structure that eurotlx.com delivers.

```
Sub Scrape()

    Dim ie As Object

    'Get rid of cached sites
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "http://www.eurotlx.com/it/strumenti/dettaglio/IT0004785355"

    While (ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4)
    DoEvents
    Wend

    Set tds = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("table_label")

    For Each TDelement In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("table_label")
      If InStr(TDelement.innerText, "Prezzo di chiusura") Then
         Range("I3") = TDelement.nextElementSibling.innerText
         Exit For
      End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Of course, the weakeness of this method is, that if the site administrator changes the innerText of "prezzo di chiusura", Excel will not be able to find its value.

Comment: tx for the answer useful to know. But is there a way to access the updated data i see in the web page or it is not possible to access the memory the web page uses?

Comment: Any macro you use will get you the value of the element once the DOM was totally loaded. Therefore, if you want to get a track of the Stock Prices Changes for every day, you have to create a task in the Windows Task Scheduler, and of course, adapt the macro to store the values in the correct place.

Comment: Probably what I want at the moment it's easier, I want just an excel file with stock and bond and a button and when I press the button I want to update the settlement prices of the day in my table. Now I can load the prices in my excel table but I noticed that not always I get elements up to date with the webpage. Surely the getelement access different area than the web page

Comment: Can you please post an URL where you don't get the same value in Excel than the value displayed in the website?

Comment: For example now in the web page for that particular bond the settlement price( Prezzo di chiusura) is 103,74 but the getelement load the previous settlement price 103,88. It's a static number is not changing continuously

Comment: with the getelements now I have the last friday settlement price 103,88 while today and in the web page I see 103,74

Comment: I am getting the actual stock price. Your problem has an easy explanation. You are getting the result of a cached site. If you want to get rid of this, and you don't use IE as your default browser, it has a really easy workaround. The answer was edited to reflect it.

Comment: Yes at the moment I use Chrome. Let me understand well, what I need to do to have the actual price if I don't use IE as default? Probably the problem is that one but I didn't understand the workaround

Comment: :-) tha answer was edited to reflect it? at the moment the only way i could find is to use IE as default :-) but I would like the chrome, is there another way?

Comment: Yes. It was edited (Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"). Unlike Internet Explorer, Google Chrome does not have a COM automation interface, which prevents you from interacting with the DOM from Excel-VBA. Hence IE is your best (only) option. My question about IE being your defaut browser was because the added command delete all cached sites, passwords, cookies, history... If IE is not your default browser, and you don't mind losing this information, you are good to go with this option.

Comment: Thanks Agustin, you were very helpful i don't have all your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector:**

You can use a CSS selector of: `table:last-child .table_label ~ td`

The element with `td` tag following last `table` tag with className `.table_label`.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the CSS selector with the `querySelector` method of `document`.

```
Debug.Print Objie.Document.querySelector("table:last-child .table_label ~ td").innerText
```